# Laravel charset - utf8

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, character-encoding, cyrillic

I'm using Laravel 5 and i'm making an `AJAX request` with which the user can create a `directory`. But if the user uses a `Cyrillic alphabet` the newly created dir appears to be strange: `РЎРЅРёРјРєРё`. This is the ajax:

```
$.ajax({
       async: true,                      
       method: 'POST',
       dataType: 'json',
       url: '../public/createfolder',
       data: {foldername: $('#folder-name').val(), "_token": csrf},
       complete: function(response) {
           console.log(response);                  
       }
});
```

And that's how I catch the request:

```
public function createFolder(){
        $foldername = $_POST['foldername'];
        $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $userid = Auth::id();
        Storage::disk('local')-> makeDirectory('uploads'.$ds.$userid.$ds.$foldername);
    }
```

How can this be avoided?

Comment: I would recommend not using user input for any of your file structure and using something completely random and unique, mapping the user input via the database. We have an internal tool we built to handle this using Flysystem (which I can't share, unfortunately). Our filenames look like `storage/media/attachments/01/b2/01b287c28676d72d6a2a0f67c3cd280e.jpg` on the system

Comment: @JoshJanusch Thanks, I may use what you've suggested. So if a user creates a new dir like "Снимки", the path shouldn't look like `storage/uploads/1/снимки` but something like `storage/uploads/1/something_random`?

Comment: Yes. Something random and unique and then you use your database to say `storage/uploads/1/снимки` is located at `storage/uploads/1/something_random`

Comment: And that way there would be no Cyrillic dirs in the filesystem, right

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your directory names are stored in the database. In this case, you can just create the actual directories with the name as their id in the database.

Also you don't really have to create a directory, even if the user thinks he's creating it. Unless you allow the user to access it through FTP, there's no need to create it. You can have a single directory for each user and assign the files in the database to a virtual directory, that's only displayed to the user, even though the files are all in the same location.